# Как сократить занимаемую память загруженного сайта?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, chrome-extension

Загруженная страница занимает 80-130мб памяти. В chrome-расширении через querySelector/removeChild чищу ненужные мне div'ы и js-скрипты из этой страницы. Но память не сокращается. Мне надо штук 20-30 таких страниц, на что памяти соответственно категорически не хватает.

Answer (score 0):

Очистка элементов и скриптов после рендера страницы не поможет, так как память уже была выделена, как сработает сборщик мусора - сложно угадать.

Попробуйте запретить загрузку ненужных JS-скриптов через [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). 
Это достаточно мощное API которое используют все популярные блокировщики рекламы и счетчиков.